# Java - Object creating itself many times - any design pattern for this?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, uml

[image: Objects relations]

i want to know what is the closest Design pattern that helps in such a situation,

an object (lets call it the original big one) takes an instance (call it INST), and check if it holds an object of a certain type(call it CRT), if so, it generates a different instance of this INST object (from within this CRT), then sends this new different instance to another object of the same kind (of the original big one ), and this other objects does the same, and so on

this stupid logic is because I'm working on a menu stuff, and each item in this menu can have extras (toppings, modifiers, etc...), if it has an extra, this extra may contain another extra and so on

:D and in the end, this all will be shown on the screen (Android)

my point is about design, not core coding

any way, the coding language is java, but any design pattern is welcome

in the end, i want to detect all the created objects, and analyze there count and relation to each other (which one belongs to the other)

Comment: why not see what aerogear or phonegap can provide you?

Comment: what's  aerogear or phonegap ?

Comment: I think what you need is Composite Design Pattern.

Comment: Something like a `LinkedList` or a tree?

Comment: @SerotoninChase THANKS ... that was what i'm searching for, please put your comment in an answer so i can vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is Composite Design Pattern.